# Solr dataimporthandler - read tab delimited file data source to add fields

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I have table in database which has some properties about different items.

I have another datasource which is a file and has data like this-

```
itemCode            warehouseCode warehouseType
abc                 123              black
abc                 456              white
xyz                 444              black
```

I can load all data from the database into the solr index using a dataimport handler. Is there a way to update all documents in the index to include the corresponding warehouseCode and warehouseType?
Here is my data-config.xml-

```
<dataSource name="itemdb"  type="JdbcDataSource" driver="org.postgresql.Driver"
                url="jdbc:postgresql://server:5432/itemdb"
                user="alice" 
                password="wonderland"/>
<dataSource name="places_file" type="FileDataSource" />

<document name="item_properties">
    <entity name="e_item" dataSource="itemdb" pk="iCode" 
             query="SELECT * from get_all_item_properties()" >
    </entity>
    <entity name="e_itemplaces" processor="LineEntityProcessor" 
                  url="/file_data.txt"  dataSource="places_file"  
                  separator="\t" rootEntity="false" header="true">

     </entity>
</document>
```

this does not load the fields from file into solr. 
the log says-

```
        Accessing File: /file_data.txt
           - Import completed successfully
```

but I get the fields from the jdbcsource only.

Comment: Are you using a fullimport?

Comment: yes. using full import.